# How to determine Ryzen cores with maximum undervolting potential?

Tags: linux, cpu, performance, amd-ryzen

I am trying to understand which cores have the maximum undervolting potential on my Ryzen CPU for per-core curve optimizer settings.  This is on a Linux system and Ryzen Master is not an option.  Given the following per-core information, which core should have the best and worst potential and why?

| Core | CPPC highest perf | Freq | Power | Voltage | Temp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 231 | 3.7GHz | 4.54W | 0.89V | 64.8C |
| 2 | 216 | 3.7GHz | 4.46W | 0.89V | 61.6C |
| 3 | 201 | 3.7GHz | 4.05W | 0.90V | 59.1C |
| 4 | 171 | 3.7GHz | 4.05W | 0.91V | 60.0C |

The CPPC value is per /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu<#>/acpi_cppc/highest_perf, the freq/power/voltage/temp values are sampled during a sustained all core workload when all cores are performing an identical task.  Please let me know if any other information needed to determine the answer.

Comment: As with most overclocking questions actually trying it out will likely give the brest results.